# UIImagePickerController crashes when switching to video from camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, ios13

I have a crash with `UIImagePickerController` on iPhones with iOS 13 (real device) after switching to video capture mode. Crash reproduces on the second presentation of `UIImagePickerControlle`r. Crash does not reproduce on versions before iOS 13 (real device). Camera and Microphone usage description keys are set in Info.plist Test app built with Xcode 11.0

Steps:

1. Present `UIImagePickerController`
2. Dismiss `UIImagePickerController`
3. Present `UIImagePickerController`
4. Tap VIDEO button - > Crash

Crash does not reproduce if I set `videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh`. But I need `UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium`.

```
@interface ViewController () < UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
@end

@implementation ViewController

#pragma mark - IBActions

- (IBAction)showPicker:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *pickerController = [UIImagePickerController new];
    pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    pickerController.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
//    pickerController.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
    pickerController.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

#pragma mark - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<UIImagePickerControllerInfoKey, id> *)info {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

@end
```

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVCaptureDevice
>   setActiveColorSpace:] Not supported - use
>   activeFormat.supportedColorSpaces'

Comment: Which iPhone model you're using? I just tried your code on an iPhone XS Max and it worked fine, even with video quality as Medium.

Comment: 11 pro. only happens on the second time I open the picker

Comment: Hope that my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65935833/4505749) helps.

Answer (score 1):

Set your video quality in pickercontroller

```
[pickerController setVideoQuality:UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame1280x720];
```